# Sending mail takes long time in localhost

Tags: php, ubuntu, sendmail

I am using Ubuntu.I installed sendmail in my local host using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Now I would like to check whether mail goes from my localhost using following php code.

```
<?php
$to = "test@test.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

When i execute the code, It takes very long time and finally echo the message as Mail Sent.
Is there any possibilities to fix this ?

Comment: upgrade your server? or maybe you have a dns lookup problem?

Comment: Run your script under `strace -f` to determine on which call it stalls.

Comment: maybe this is a better question for Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 15):

Edit the file `/etc/hosts` and make sure the first line is the following:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost myhostname

Edit the `sendmail` configuration file ( `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` in Ubuntu) and Uncomment the `line #O`:

> O HostsFile=/etc/hosts

Restart the computer, or run `sudo service sendmail restart`.

The computer should boot up much faster now and the `mail()` function should return almost immediately.

**HOWEVER**, the emails won't actually be sent unless you follow step 5.

You must new use the sendmail `-f` option whenever using the mail function.

For example:

```
mail('recipient@somewhere.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null, '-fsender@somewhere.com');
```

Comment: step 5?   There are no 'steps' in your answer.

Comment: step 5 comes from this question http://serverfault.com/questions/173762/php-mail-function-painfully-slow-on-local-development-machine/221894#221894

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has already been answered, but I'm posting this in the hope it may help someone else looking for a different solution to this issue.

For me, I just needed to put my server's Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) into `/etc/mailname`. For example: `server.example.com`.

Restart Sendmail to apply the changes.

`$ sudo service sendmail restart`

Answer (score 2):

This answer helped me https://serverfault.com/a/221894/186680

Postfix and sendmail where installed. Removed sendmail `Yum remove sendmail`

Answer (score 0):

The delay is usually indicating a DNS time-out. Is your machine configured with proper DNS entries? I would try doing a test using mail on the command line as this would isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know Sendmail well, you are probably bettter off installing some other MTA. `ssmtpd` was already suggested in another answer; a common choice is Posfix.